# Python: how to compute the distance between cells?

Tags: python

Let's suppose I want to compute the distance between cells in a square grid `5x5`. The distance between two cells is `100m`.

Each cell of the grid is number between `0` and `24`

```
0   1  2  3  4
5   6  7  8  9
10 11 12 13 14
15 16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23 24
```

For instance:

```
distance between cell 0 and 3 is 300
distance between cell 2 and 7 is 100
distance between cell 11 and 19 is 400
```

I have to count the distance as different between `x` and `y` location of the cells.

```
gs = 5 ## Cells per side
S = gs*gs ## Grid Size
r0 = 100 ## distance between two cells

for i in range(0, S):
    for j in range(0, S):
        if i == j: continue
        x = int(floor(i/gs))
        y = int(floor(j/gs))
        dist = x*r0 + abs(j-i)*r0
```

but it is not the right solution

Comment: Can you share the expected output?

Comment: @yatu I added few examples

Comment: Calculate sum of row and column distances. Row distance is round_down(cell_distance/width)

Comment: you want basic pythagorean :
`sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2) * 100`

Comment: Yes but how do you want to store the result? IIUC the result to this sould be a 3D ndarray

Answer (score 1):

```
# n1, n2 = cell numbers
cellsize = 100.0
x1,x2 = n1%gs, n2%gs
y1,y2 = n1//gs, n2//gs
dist = sqrt( float(x1-x2)**2 + float(y1-y2)**2)  # pythagoras theorem
dist *= cellsize
```

Answer (score 0):

you should consider co-ordinate and not the cell number

```
gs = 5 ## Cells per side
S = gs*gs ## Grid Size
r0 = 100 ## distance between two cells

for i in range(0, S):
    for j in range(0, S):
        if i == j: continue
           xi = int(i/gs)
           yi = i % gs
           xj = int(j/gs)
           yj = j % gs
           dist = r0 * (abs(xi-xj) + abs(yi-yj))
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a way to do that:

```
r = 100

grid = ((0,   1,  2,  3,  4),
        (5,   6,  7,  8,  9),
        (10, 11, 12, 13, 14),
        (15, 16, 17, 18, 19),
        (20, 21, 22, 23, 24))

def coord(n):
    for x, line in enumerate(grid):
        if n not in line:
            continue
        y = line.index(n)
        return x, y

def dist(n, m):
        xn, yn = coord(n)
        xm, ym = coord(m)
        return r * (abs(xn - xm) + abs(yn - ym))

print(dist(0, 3))  # 300
print(dist(2, 7))  # 100
print(dist(11, 19)) # 400
```

the idea is to get the coordinates of your numbers first and then calculating the 'distance'.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```py
n = 5 # row length in array

def distance(a, b):
    distance = (abs(a // n - b // n) + abs(a % n - b % n)) * 100
    return "distance between cell %s and %s is %s" % (a, b, distance)

print(distance(0, 3))
print(distance(2, 7))
print(distance(11, 19))
```

Output:

```sh
distance between cell 0 and 3 is 300
distance between cell 2 and 7 is 100
distance between cell 11 and 19 is 400
```

Where `a` and `b` are your cells, and `n` is a length of the row in array, in your example is `5`.

Answer (score 0):

We just need to get the **row** and **column** number of every number. Then a difference b/w the two and multiplied by 100 will give you answer

```
def get_row_col(num):
    for i,g in enumerate(grid):
        if num in g:
            col = g.index(num)
            row = i
    return row, col

num1 = get_row_col(11)
num2 = get_row_col(19)
print (abs(num1[0] - num2[0])*100) + (abs(num1[1]-num2[1])*100)
```

One can enhance this code to check if number is present or not.